# Creating a Data Extension via SSJS SOAP call

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api, dataextensions, ssjs

**EDIT**

The issue was that I have SUBSCRIBER_KEY functionality turned on for my account, so I need to set the SendableSubscriberField to 'Subscriber Key' or the call will fail.

---

I have been able to utilize similar SSJS code previously and have mimicked some similar questions from SFSE, but everything I try, winds up with me receiving a 405 Error Method Not Allowed.

If anyone can help me find what I am missing/forgetting to do/doing wrong in the below snippet, it would be GREATLY appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
   </head>
<body>
<script runat="server"> 

Platform.Load("core", "1");     

    var user = 'User';
    var pass = 'Pass';
    var payload = '';
    var endpoint = 'https://webservice.exacttarget.com/Service.asmx'
    var result;

    // Create SOAP Call

    payload += '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>';
    payload += '<Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">';
    payload += '        <Header>';
    payload += '            <Action mustUnderstand="1">Create</Action>';
    payload += '            <Security xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">';
    payload += '                <UsernameToken>';
    payload += '                    <Username>' + user + '</Username>';
    payload += '                    <Password>' + pass + '</Password>';
    payload += '                </UsernameToken>';
    payload += '            </Security>';
    payload += '         </Header>';
    payload += '        <Body>';
    payload += '            <CreateRequest xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI" >';
    payload += '              <Options></Options>';
    payload += '              <Objects xmlns:ns1="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI" xsi:type="ns1:DataExtension">';
    payload += '                <CustomerKey>CustomerKey</CustomerKey>';
    payload += '                <Name>CustomerKey</Name>';
    payload += '                <IsSendable>true</IsSendable>/';
    payload += '                <SendableDataExtensionField>';
    payload += '                  <CustomerKey>EmailAddress_Key</CustomerKey>';
    payload += '                  <Name>EmailAddress</Name>';
    payload += '                  <FieldType>EmailAddress</FieldType>';
    payload += '                </SendableDataExtensionField>';
    payload += '                <SendableSubscriberField>';
    payload += '                  <Name>Email Address</Name>';
    payload += '                  <Value></Value>';
    payload += '                </SendableSubscriberField>';
    payload += '                <Fields>';
    payload += '                    <Field>';
    payload += '                        <CustomerKey>EmailAddress_Key</CustomerKey>';
    payload += '                        <Name>EmailAddress</Name>';
    payload += '                        <FieldType>EmailAddress</FieldType>';
    payload += '                    </Field>';
    payload += '                    <Field>';
    payload += '                        <CustomerKey>ChannelUser_Key</CustomerKey>';
    payload += '                        <Name>ChannelUser</Name>';
    payload += '                        <FieldType>Text</FieldType>';
    payload += '                    </Field>';
    payload += '                </Fields> ';
    payload += '              </Objects> ';  
    payload += '            </CreateRequest>';
    payload += '       </Body>';
    payload += '</Envelope>';

    try {
        result = HTTP.Post(endpoint, "text/xml", payload, ["SOAPAction"], ["Create"]);
    } catch (e) {
        Write(Stringify(e));
    }

    Write(Stringify(result));

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is there any reason you have to use the SOAP call? Can't you use the out of box SSJS function?

Comment: Have to create across different MIDs (not related) and out of the box SSJS will only work on the MID it is built on.

Comment: Do you have the right endpoint URL for the stack the MID(s) are one?  Also, you might try using the SJS library 1.1.1.   (Just guesses at this point)  :)

Comment: I do have the right stackendpoint, I will try using 1.1.1. Guesses are definitely appreciated! I am at my wits end on this one.

Comment: No such luck, changing the SSJS library did not help. :(

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why you would want to make an HTTP.POST call to the SOAP API to achieve this.

If you use the platform API functions available in SSJS (or AMPscript), that will take care of authentication and also resolve the correct Web Service endpoint.

Here's how you would create a Sendable DE using platform API functions in SSJS:

```js
<script runat="server">
Platform.Load("Core","1");

var de = Platform.Function.CreateObject("DataExtension");

Platform.Function.SetObjectProperty(de, "Name", "My Sendable DE"); 
Platform.Function.SetObjectProperty(de, "Description", "A DE created via SSJS"); 
Platform.Function.SetObjectProperty(de, "IsSendable", "true"); 
Platform.Function.SetObjectProperty(de, "IsTestable", "false"); 

var deFields = Platform.Function.CreateObject("DataExtensionField");
Platform.Function.SetObjectProperty(deFields, "FieldType", "Text"); 
Platform.Function.SetObjectProperty(deFields, "Name", "Id"); 
Platform.Function.SetObjectProperty(deFields, "MaxLength", 18); 
Platform.Function.SetObjectProperty(deFields, "IsPrimaryKey", "true"); 
Platform.Function.SetObjectProperty(deFields, "IsNillable", "false"); 
Platform.Function.SetObjectProperty(deFields, "IsRequired", "true"); 
Platform.Function.AddObjectArrayItem(de, "Fields", deFields);

Platform.Function.SetObjectProperty(de,"SendableDataExtensionField",deFields)

var deFields = Platform.Function.CreateObject("DataExtensionField");
Platform.Function.SetObjectProperty(deFields, "FieldType", "Text"); 
Platform.Function.SetObjectProperty(deFields, "Name", "Name"); 
Platform.Function.SetObjectProperty(deFields, "MaxLength", 50); 
Platform.Function.AddObjectArrayItem(de, "Fields", deFields);

var deFields = Platform.Function.CreateObject("DataExtensionField");
Platform.Function.SetObjectProperty(deFields, "FieldType", "EmailAddress"); 
Platform.Function.SetObjectProperty(deFields, "Name", "Email Address"); 
Platform.Function.SetObjectProperty(deFields, "IsNillable", "false"); 
Platform.Function.SetObjectProperty(deFields, "IsRequired", "true"); 
Platform.Function.AddObjectArrayItem(de, "Fields", deFields);

var subscriberAttr = Platform.Function.CreateObject("Attribute");
Platform.Function.SetObjectProperty(subscriberAttr, "Name", "Subscriber Key");
Platform.Function.SetObjectProperty(subscriberAttr, "Value", "Id");
Platform.Function.SetObjectProperty(de, "SendableSubscriberField", subscriberAttr);

var statusAndRequestID = [0,0];

var statMsg = Platform.Function.InvokeCreate(de, StatusAndRequestID, null);
Platform.Response.Write('status message: ' + statMsg);
</script>
```

In the above example, I've created the Subscriber relationship based on Subscriber Key = the Id field in my DE. However you could change this relationship to be based on email address by changing the following lines:

```js
Platform.Function.SetObjectProperty(subscriberAttr, "Name", "Subscriber Key");
Platform.Function.SetObjectProperty(subscriberAttr, "Value", "Id");
```

To:

```js
Platform.Function.SetObjectProperty(subscriberAttr, "Name", "Email Address");
Platform.Function.SetObjectProperty(subscriberAttr, "Value", "Email Address");
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @EliotHarper, utilizing the  platform API is always a great capability, but the purpose of POSTing was to make calls from one BU into others inside an E1 environment all within 1 script activity.

Answer (score 1):

I got this working by making few changes. the endpoint looks wrong to me.

MY instance is on s10 stack. so I have used the below endpoint and it works.

https://webservice.s10.exacttarget.com/Service.asmx

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<script runat="server">
Platform.Load("core", "1");    
var payload = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <s:Envelope 
xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" 
xmlns:a="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" 
xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-
wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">  <s:Header>     <a:Action 
s:mustUnderstand="1">Create</a:Action>     
<a:MessageID>urn:uuid:7e0cca04-57bd-4481-864c-
6ea8039d2ea0</a:MessageID>     <a:ReplyTo>    <a:Address>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/role/anonymous</a:Address>     </a:ReplyTo>     <a:To s:mustUnderstand="1">https://webservice.s10.exacttarget.com/Service.asmx</a:To>      <Security xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">                    <UsernameToken>                        <Username>*****</Username>                        <Password>****</Password>                    </UsernameToken>                </Security>  </s:Header> <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">     <CreateRequest xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">        <Options/>        <Objects xsi:type="DataExtension">           <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true"/>           <ObjectID xsi:nil="true"/>           <Name>Sam_DE</Name>           <IsSendable>false</IsSendable>           <Fields>              <Field>                 <Name>EmailAddress</Name>                 <FieldType>EmailAddress</FieldType>                 <IsPrimaryKey>true</IsPrimaryKey>                 <IsRequired>true</IsRequired>              </Field>              <Field>                 <Name>SubscriberKey</Name>                 <FieldType>Text</FieldType>                 <IsRequired>false</IsRequired>              </Field>              <Field>                 <Name>Date</Name>                 <FieldType>Date</FieldType>                 <DefaultValue>getdate()</DefaultValue>                 <IsRequired>true</IsRequired>              </Field>              <Field>                 <Name>Average_Order_Value</Name>                 <FieldType>Decimal</FieldType>                 <IsRequired>true</IsRequired>                 <Precision>10</Precision>                 <Scale>2</Scale>              </Field>              <Field>                 <Name>Is_Proofing_Customer</Name>                 <FieldType>Boolean</FieldType>                 <DefaultValue>true</DefaultValue>                 <IsRequired>true</IsRequired>              </Field>              <Field>                 <Name>Number_of_Clusters</Name>                 <FieldType>Number</FieldType>                 <IsRequired>false</IsRequired>              </Field>              <Field>                 <Name>Telephone</Name>                 <FieldType>Phone</FieldType>                 <IsRequired>false</IsRequired>              </Field>              <Field>                 <Name>Locale</Name>                 <FieldType>Locale</FieldType>                 <IsRequired>false</IsRequired>              </Field>           </Fields>           <CustomerKey>SamDE01</CustomerKey>        </Objects>     </CreateRequest> </s:Body></s:Envelope>';
var endpoint = 'https://webservice.s10.exacttarget.com/Service.asmx';
var result;

// Create SOAP Call


try {
  //Write(payload);
    result = HTTP.Post(endpoint, "text/xml", payload, ["SOAPAction"], ["Create"]);
} catch (e) {
    Write(Stringify(e));
}

Write(Stringify(result));

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hello Praveen, thank you for catching that. I did copy the wrong link in my question, but the issue was actually that I had Subscriber_Key turned on for my account and I could not have the SendableSubscriberField be Email Address.

Comment: oh cool. Glad you figured the issue @Gortonington